# vertical dropdown menu collapse

Tags: javascript

I have made a vertical menu with 4 submenu.
The image is in attachment named image1.

Those submenu are dropdown when a submenu is clicked it expands and shows the submenu items.
Image 2.

When the submenu item is clicked a new page opens as if 1 item is cicked a new page will open.
There is a back button on that newly opened page and when I click on it it comes back to the main page.

But the problem is that the submenu which was clicked get collapsed.I want that it should remain expanded.
I think the problem could be solved from javascript side but I am not able to do that.
Please help me.

**javascript**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {

        $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active'); 
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 
        var checkElement = $(this).next();

        if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) { 
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');    
            checkElement.slideUp('normal'); 
        } 

        if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) { 
            $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');                 
            checkElement.slideDown('normal'); 
        } 

        if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) { 
            return true; 
        } else { 
            return false; 
        }

        if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {           
            checkElement.slideDown('normal'); 
        } 
    });

    $('#cssmenu>ul>li').append('<span class="holder"></span>');
 });
```

Comment: I think it could be solved from the javascript only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are leaving the page you are losing state.  You need to implement some kind of state persistence.   Since you insist on ONLY using Javascript,  then I would say try using local storage....

[Window.localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

If you are willing to use something other than javascript, you could just create a session and store the state of the menu there so when the user comes back, you can set the menu to the previous state.

**UPDATE**

You will probably have to tweak this code a bit.  You may need to make sure that thisval contains a value before trying to trigger the click event on it.  You may also need to trigger the click on the element before the a because the click on the a will just take you back to the page you were just at.   OK, see if that works for you...

```
//this will fire on page load...
var thisval = localstorage.getItem('menu-pos');
if (thisval) {
    $("span:contains('"+thisval+"')").closest('ul').closest('a').trigger('click');
}
//this will fire on click
$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {

    var thisval = $(this).find('span').html();
    localstorage.setItem("menu-pos", thisval);

    //rest of the code...
});
```

Comment: I am using ewd code and dont want to do the changes there.because there are many pages then which i would have to change.Pls suggest something in javascript only.

Comment: how to create session in javascript for this.I am not knowing much about java.

Comment: $('#cssmenu>ul>li').tigger('click');

Comment: Do this .trigger could help in any manner. when I am using this .trigger the last submenu remains open after coming back from the next page.

Answer (score 1):

```
    **EWD**

     <td>
<div id="boxContent">
<div class="txtHeading"><b>Practice Management Software</b></div>
 <div style="width:948px; height:100%;">
 <div style="height:100%; width:680px;"></div>
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="padding2">
     <tr>
     <td>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>

   <li class='active'><a href=#><span>MCTVistA</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>OPD PIMS</span></a>
      <ul>
           <ewd:if firstvalue="#ROLE" operation="=" secondvalue="1" >
             <li><a href="registration.ewd"><span>Registration</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="registrationemg.ewd" class="dislink" ><span>Emergency Registration</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="registrationold.ewd" class="dislink" ><span>Old Registration</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="search.ewd"><span>Patient Search</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="advancesearch.ewd"><span>Advance Search</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="opdSearch.ewd"><span>OPD List</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="opdReport.ewd"><span>OPD Reports</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="opdcensus.ewd"><span>OPD Census</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="billRpt.ewd"><span>Billing Report</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="opdRptVisit.ewd"><span>Visit Report</span></a></li>
          <ewd:elseif firstvalue="#ROLE" operation="=" secondvalue="5" >
             <li><a href="registration.ewd"><span>Registration</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="registrationemg.ewd" class="dislink"><span>Emergency Registration</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="search.ewd"><span>Patient Search</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="advancesearch.ewd"><span>Advance Search</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="opdSearch.ewd"><span>OPD List</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="billRpt.ewd"><span>Billing Report</span></a></li>
          <ewd:elseif firstvalue="#ROLE" operation="=" secondvalue="6" >
             <li><a href="registration.ewd"><span>Registration</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="search.ewd"><span>Patient Search</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="advancesearch.ewd"><span>Advance Search</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="opdSearch.ewd"><span>OPD List</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="billRpt.ewd"><span>Billing Report</span></a></li>
          <ewd:else>
             <li><a href="ewdLogout.ewd"><span>User Role Undefined</span></a></li>
          </ewd:if>




      </ul>
   </li>


  <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Services Billing</span></a>
          <ul>
          <ewd:if firstvalue="#ROLE" operation="=" secondvalue="1" >
            <li><a href="billTc.ewd"><span>Make Billing</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="billSearch.ewd"><span>Search Billing</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="billReport.ewd"><span>Billing Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="search2.ewd"><span>Search Patient</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="billCatAdd.ewd"><span>Add Category</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="billCatSea.ewd"><span>Search Category</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="billSCatAdd.ewd"><span>Add Sub Category</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="billSCatSea.ewd"><span>Search Sub Category</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="billSerAdd.ewd"><span>Add Service</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="billSerSea.ewd"><span>Search Service</span></a></li>
         <ewd:elseif firstvalue="#ROLE" operation="=" secondvalue="6" >
            <li><a href="billTc.ewd"><span>Make Billing</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="billSearch.ewd"><span>Search Billing</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="billReport.ewd"><span>Billing Report</span></a></li>
         <ewd:elseif firstvalue="#ROLESBILL" operation="=" secondvalue="1" > 
            <li><a href="billTc.ewd"><span>Make Billing</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="billSearch.ewd"><span>Search Billing</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="billReport.ewd"><span>Billing Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="search2.ewd"><span>Search Patient</span></a></li>
          <ewd:else>
             <li><a href="ewdLogout.ewd"><span>User Role Undefined</span></a></li>
            </ewd:if>
          </ul>
        </li>

    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>IPD PIMS</span></a>
            <ul>

          <ewd:if firstvalue="#ROLE" operation="=" secondvalue="1" >
            <li><a href="tca.ewd"><span>Admission</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="tct.ewd"><span>Ward Transfer</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="tcb.ewd"><span>Bed Switch</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="tcd.ewd"><span>Discharge</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="tcadt.ewd"><span>IPD View/Edit/Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="tcds.ewd"><span>Discharge Summary</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="admsearch.ewd"><span>Admission Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="dissearch.ewd"><span>Discharge Report</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="ipdBmWard.ewd"><span>Bed Management</span></a></li>
        <ewd:elseif firstvalue="#ROLE" operation="=" secondvalue="6" >
            <li><a href="tca.ewd"><span>Admission</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="tct.ewd"><span>Ward Transfer</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="tcb.ewd"><span>Bed Switch</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="tcd.ewd"><span>Discharge</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="tcadt.ewd"><span>IPD View/Edit/Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="tcds.ewd"><span>Discharge Summary</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="admsearch.ewd"><span>Admission Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="dissearch.ewd"><span>Discharge Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="ipdBmWard.ewd"><span>Bed Management</span></a></li>
        <ewd:elseif firstvalue="#ROLE" operation="=" secondvalue="3" >  
            <li><a href="tct.ewd"><span>Ward Transfer</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="tcb.ewd"><span>Bed Switch</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="tcd.ewd"><span>Discharge</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="tcadt.ewd"><span>IPD View/Edit/Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="tcds.ewd"><span>Discharge Summary</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="admsearch.ewd"><span>Admission Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="dissearch.ewd"><span>Discharge Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="ipdBmWard.ewd"><span>Bed Management</span></a></li>
        <ewd:elseif firstvalue="#ROLE" operation="=" secondvalue="10" > 
            <li><a href="tcadt.ewd"><span>IPD View/Edit/Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="tcds.ewd"><span>Discharge Summary</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="admsearch.ewd"><span>Admission Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="dissearch.ewd"><span>Discharge Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="ipdBmWard.ewd"><span>Bed Management</span></a></li>
        <ewd:elseif firstvalue="#ROLEIPD" operation="=" secondvalue="1" >
            <li><a href="tca.ewd"><span>Admission</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="tcadt.ewd"><span>IPD View/Edit/Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="admsearch.ewd"><span>Admission Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="ipdBmWard.ewd"><span>Bed Management</span></a></li>
         <ewd:else>
             <li><a href="ewdLogout.ewd"><span>User Role Undefined</a></li>
          </ewd:if>   
            </ul>
      </li>  
<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Reports</span></a>
            <ul>

          <ewd:if firstvalue="#ROLE" operation="=" secondvalue="1" >
            <li><a href="rptOpdCensus.ewd"><span>OPD Census Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="rptIpdCensus.ewd"><span>IPD Census Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="rptSBillCensus.ewd"><span>Services Bill Census Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="rptDcr.ewd"><span>Daily Collection Report</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="rptOpdOperator.ewd"><span>OPD Operator Report</span></a></li>
         <ewd:else>
             <li><a href="ewdLogout.ewd"><span>User Role Undefined</a></li>
          </ewd:if>   
            </ul>
      </li>  


</ul>
</td>
```

Comment: looks like html to me

Comment: or you suggest what to do